# Error while trying to get token for outlook REST api

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get outlook mails in my application using Outlook REST APIS

I have registered my application in AAD using my outlook account.

I have managed to get authorization code using:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/5d313248-7b5c-46a6-9d14-605dce8294c0/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=aef57953-e481-44eb-8d97-60cf78658bdf&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Foutlook.office.com%2Fmail.read

However when i use code received from the redirect request I get:

{
"error":"invalid_client",
"error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 8305c47e-aabf-4837-bcbc-92169e8016a5\r\nCorrelation ID: 986e4afe-bd40-4717-b712-034227762f19\r\nTimestamp: 2016-04-05 21:34:37Z",

"error_codes":[70002,50012],
"timestamp":"2016-04-05 21:34:37Z",
"trace_id":"8305c47e-aabf-4837-bcbc-92169e8016a5",
"correlation_id":"986e4afe-bd40-4717-b712-034227762f19"
}

I have tried same from Java code and using REST client both.

Anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Maybe your access token has expired. Please renew it before 
submitting the request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `Authorization Code Grant Flow` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/azure/dn645542.aspx, you're missing the step of acquiring access token (Step 4 in the picture below).

[image]

Using the code, you would need to get the access token and then use that access token you should be able to access Outlook REST API.